# RoomDatabase Callback deprecated

Tags: android, android-room, androidx

On building the app I get these:

```
[deprecation] mCallbacks in RoomDatabase has been deprecated
```

Not sure how to fix it. Here're the dependencies:

```
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.1.0-alpha04"
implementation 'androidx.room:room-rxjava2:2.1.0-alpha04'
annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.1.0-alpha04"
```

Is it because I'm running the alpha version?

Comment: mCallbacks was available as a protected field and was deprecated because it will be hidden in the next releases.

Comment: Alright, so I don't need to change anything right?

Comment: Nope, unless you have some code that access that field directly.

Comment: I have the same warning, but my app is not compiling.